# Why is NSUserDefaults not saving my values?

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

Hi I am trying to use `NSUserDefaults` to save some default values in database. I am able to save the values in the `NSUserDefaults` (even checked it in `NSLog`).
Now I need the values in app delegate when the application is restarted. But I am not getting anything in the `NSUserDefaults`. Following is my code from my class where I save the values in `NSUserDefaults`:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

            [prefs setObject:appDel.dictProfile forKey:@"dict"];
            NSLog(@"%@",[prefs valueForKey:@"dict"]);
```

Following is my code from App Delegagte:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSLog(@"%@",[prefs valueForKey:@"dict"]);
```

the above code always returns me null.
Can some one please help me?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

If you terminate your app by pressing the home button (in the Simulator or on the device), your `NSUserDefaults` will get saved.

If you terminate your app by pressing "Stop" in Xcode (in the Simulator or on the device), your `NSUserDefaults` *might* get saved, but there's a good chance they won't. `NSUserDefaults` persists any changes periodically, and if you terminate the process before they've been persisted, they'll be gone. You can force the save by calling:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

### Addendum:

In iOS4 (this answer was originally written when iOS3 was the public release), your `NSUserDefaults` may not get saved when pressing the home button. Manually calling `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]` in `applicationDidEnterBackground:` should ensure that your `NSUserDefaults` are saved correctly (this should really be a built-in behaviour IMO).

Comment: iOS 8 (iPad mini), I'm having this exact problem, and `synchronize` in both `appWillTerminate` and `appDidEnterBackground` is not helping.  Gah!!!

Comment: According to the comments above `synchronize()` in Apple's source code file `NSUserDefaults.h`: "`-synchronize` is deprecated."

Comment: For the record, the current (2020) documentation for NSUserDefaults states: `-synchronize: Waits for any pending asynchronous updates to the defaults database and returns; this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used.`

Comment: I believe I am hitting this same scenario (command-period in xcode does not save the user prefs) and it is 2023 and I'm on iOS16

Answer (score 10):

This code works fine for me .

```
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if (standardUserDefaults) {
    [standardUserDefaults setObject:myString forKey:@"Prefs"];
    [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't really add anything to the discussion; the code snippets are already available up-thread.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say whether you are running on a device or in the simulator, but if you restart the application in the simulator, all preferences will be reset between launches if you launch from Xcode. The preferences will only be preserved if you relaunch from the simulator itself.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct.  (It may have been with an older version of the sdk.)

Comment: I agree with Brad. Simulator retains preference values during its relaunch from xcode. It only loses preferences when we delete the application from simulator.

Comment: The current version of the simulator (iOS 4) retains preferences so my answer is not longer applicable. It was originally written when iOS 3 were current.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was saving and retrieving a string. When I synchronized after saving and then retrived in another thread, it was not working properly. The problem was solved by synchronizing both after saving and before retreiving.