# How to use pList in iOS Programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Recently, I'm a senior in high school, and I'm interested in making apps for iPhone. Recently, one of my apps came out: NBlock. It's a puzzle app and it's very challenging. However, it has a few problems. The high scores are not saved. I've been told to use a plist. Any tips?

Comment: You could start by reading [apple's plist tutorial]( http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/QuickStartPlist/QuickStartPlist.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The URL based method for this:

```
// Get the URL for the document directory
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSURL *documentDirectoryURL = [[fileManager URLsForDocumentDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] objectAtIndex:0];

// Turn the filename into a string safe for use in a URL
NSString *safeString = [@"scores.plist" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Create an array for the score
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];      
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:score]];

// Write this array to a URL
NSURL *arrayURL = [NSURL URLWithString:safeString relativeToURL:documentDirectoryURL];
[array writeToURL:arrayURL atomically:YES];
```

Comment: To me it seems much cleaner and clearer to use `-[NSURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:]` for file URLs instead of the relative URL. This would remove the need for percent escaping of the path and is generally less error prone.

Answer (score 3):

I'd avoid using a plist. The easiest way to save simple data in an application, by far, is `NSUserDefaults`.

Check out [this tutorial](http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/20/using_nsuserdefaults/) for a simple guide on how to use `NSUserDefaults`. Always be sure to [`synchronize`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622754/nsuserdefault-not-able-to-save-values/2622940#2622940) `NSUserDefaults` when you're done writing to them.

If you're looking for a more powerful (but more complex) way to save data, check out Apple's guide to using [`Core Data`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: I thought NSUserDefaults was recommended for standardised default settings that you want to persist related to language preferences and the like?

Answer (score 3):

Heres what you want:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"scores.plist"];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];      
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:score]];        
[array writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

And to add new scores do `initWithContentsOfFile:@"scores.plist"` instead of `init` in the declaration of `array`. You can optionally use NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Can somebody who's on a pc please format the source code in my post right? Its impossible on my ipod....

Comment: What do you mean by that? `writeToURL:automatically:`?

Comment: But why would you need the URL method if you aren't actually writing to a URL??

Comment: Just because it's a local file doesn't mean that it is not a URL. IIRC the recommendation is to move away from path based file methods to URL based ones. Your answer is fine and works - I just wanted to show another way of doing the same thing using URLs instead of paths.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look into NSKeyedArchiver/Unarchiver. You can save pretty much anything you want; NSUserDefaults, in my experience, dumps your data if you kill your app from the tray. Core data is really used better if you're managing large amounts of data with databases such as sqlite.

Comment: I've never had that issue with a properly `synchronize`d `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks. NSUserDefaults is really only good if you're just saving a simple string or something like that (I guess the asker might be a good candidate), as long as it can be permanently saved.

Comment: Check out the link I added in my answer to see how to deal with that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the below code will work and pretty straight forward unless custom object data types(Its a different story again) are used:

```
NSString* plistPath = nil;
NSFileManager* manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 if ((plistPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PathTo.plist"])) 
   {
    if ([manager isWritableFileAtPath:plistPath]) 
     {
       NSMutableDictionary* infoDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
      [infoDict setObject:@"foo object" forKey:@"fookey"];
      [infoDict writeToFile:plistPath atomically:NO];
      [manager setAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDate date] forKey:NSFileModificationDate] ofItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] error:nil];
     }
   }
```

setting the date attribute might be helpful to check when is the last time score was updated.