# Store two user defined strings in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I am new to iOS programming - I have written an iOS app for a company that uses the app for their workers to log in when they go to work, and to log out when they leave. (They often work on remote places).

All I need now is a way to store two simple strings.
1. String is the user name
2. String is a salted md5 password

Then the user doesn't need to write all the credentials every time he wants to login and out.

What is the simples? SQLite, CoreData, Plst?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059966/how-to-use-plist-in-ios-programming/7060019#7060019):

I'd avoid using a plist. The easiest way to save simple data in an application, by far, is [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Check out [this tutorial](http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/20/using_nsuserdefaults/) for a simple guide on how to use `NSUserDefaults`. Always be sure to [`synchronize`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622754/nsuserdefault-not-able-to-save-values/2622940#2622940) `NSUserDefaults` when you're done writing to them.

Example:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// Storing an NSString:
NSString *user = @"MyUsername";
[prefs setObject:user forKey:@"username"];
[prefs synchronize];
```

Later:

```
// Retrieving an NSString:
NSString *savedUserName = [prefs stringForKey:@"username"];
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know it was THIS easy!
I have actually set up an SQLite, but it's extreme overkill for a username and a password - But now I know how to use SQLite AND NSUserDefaults :)
BTW, how much data can you store in NSUserDefaults?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510123/is-there-any-limit-in-storing-values-in-nsuserdefaults