# NSUserDefault Maximum Size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, size, nsuserdefaults

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any limit in storing values in NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510123/is-there-any-limit-in-storing-values-in-nsuserdefaults)

How much data i can save on NSUserDefaults . Is there is storage size is different for all devices. or same for all devices .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why on earth will you want to store so much data in `NSUserDefaults`?

`NSUserDefaults' should not be used as a global dictionary.

Try using property lists & core data.

Comment: maybe saad need(ed) to share data between apps.

Comment: So the down vote was coz he did not specify that?