# Saving entire NSArray in SQLite

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sqlite, nsarray

I want to saving entire array into SQLite. I am getting an array having many other arrays in that.
Is it possible ? If so please let tell me.

I have tried this  - But  "ERROR TO SAVE DATA"

```
NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:@"events_data"];
 sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (event_array) VALUES (\"%@\")", array];

                           const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

                           sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
                           if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
                           {

                               NSLog(@"DATA SAVED TO DB");

                           } else {
                               NSLog(@"ERROR TO SAVE DATA");
                           }
                           sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                           sqlite3_close(contactDB);
                           }
```

If it is possible please tell me how to retrieve it also.

Comment: That was a similar topic a week ago or so.  To wrap it up, use XML to save your array data.

Comment: If you want the elements of the array inserted as individual rows, using vanilla SQLite, you will need to insert them individually (though it certainly can be done in a relatively compact loop).

Comment: (Hint: When you get an error in SQLite, dump the value from `sqlite3_errmsg()`.  The error message is almost always quite useful.)

Answer (score 0):

You need [not use sqlite directly in iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started). Indeed, you should wrap the persistent object in an [NSManagedObject](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/). To retrieve the object, simply create an [NSFetchRequest](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/), set its entity, and have the context execute it, which will return a standard [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/) of [NSManagedObject](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/)s, which you can iterate over. Hope this helped, please leave a comment if you have further issues.

Comment: is there any issue using NSUserdefaults. What is the size limit for NSUserdefaults ?

Comment: Doesn't appear [to be a size limit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7510178/783412), but you can't [persist just any type](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7510246/783412).