# IS there any restriction in length of string data in plist for mobile application development?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, plist

I am trying to fetch data to my mobile game start screen from a .plist file. whenever i add more lines of texts (more than 120 lines of text), the start screen text will not be displayed., but when i shorten length of text, it will be displayed. Is there any restriction in length of string data in plist file? 
Please help. I am stuck in this issue more than 8 hours.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any limit in storing values in NSUserDefaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510123/is-there-any-limit-in-storing-values-in-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: You might want to take a different approach to loading the text...

Comment: Agree with l'L'l. It sounds like the data is static. I would store the information in a json file bundled with the game. Many posts on here about how to do it (i've answered one similar in obj-c) but you could look here https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-json-in-swift--cms-25335

Comment: Are you sure it's not a render issue? Maybe the container is too small and just doesn't render at all if the content is too big.