# Update/Modify values in a property list

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

Is it possible to update values in a existing property list programatically? If so, how?

I did bit of a search on this but didn't find anything useful.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post a few lines of code showing the objects' structure your using?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059966/how-to-use-plist-in-ios-programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can read the list with

```
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:file]
```

or

```
[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:file]
```

Afterwards you can modify the Array or Dictionary and write it out again with:

```
[array writeToFile:file atomically:YES]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update yourapp.infoplist runtime. then answer is NO.

But if you are using custom plist then you will able to modified as @Bernhard Harrer told.

Comment: No, this is not the info.plist. Just a custom plist I created.