# UIViewController presented once when the app launches

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults, xib, uivewcontroller

A scree is the first page when the application launches. The user can only click on the accept & continue button to proceed.
This page only appears once initially & when the user had clicked on the accept & continue button, this page doesn’t appear in subsequent launch of this application.
Only when the user has wiped clean all data related to this application does this page appear on startup again.

Comment: ok if possible then delete the comment : 
no problem, just informing you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSUserDefaults`

**//When launched for the first time set value like this :**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"YES" forKey:@"LaunchingFirstTime"];
```

after that

```
NSString *launch = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"LaunchingFirstTime"];

if([launch isEqualToString:@"YES"]){
    //Don't Show Screen
}
else{
    //Show Screen
}
```

**Hope this will help you**

Comment: Xman i used this logic- (void)viewDidLoad

   
  
    
    
        welcomePage *temp = [[welcomePage alloc]initWithNibName:@"welcomePage" bundle:nil];
        
        [self presentViewController:temp animated:YES completion:^(void){}];

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"screen");
           } but its showing Warning: Attempt to present <welcomePage: 0x8245330> on <ViewController: 0x7157560> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
and welcome screen did not come

Comment: @Ram : that is diffrent issue..

Comment: this logic is working but when did i quite the apps and again its coming

Comment: NSUserDefaults might not have a chance to save depending on how the process is terminated.  check this [old question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2622754/2407907)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create one view controller. And, load it at the start of the app.
2. When user click on "accept & continue", go ahead and save one BOOL value in Plist, NSUserDefault.
3. When you load the app next time check this value and show the screen depending on BOOL value you have saved.
4. Do the same thing when user has clear the data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are talking about splash screen. If you want some custom buttons like accept and continue, you can create a custom view and call that view from AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunching` method. On button click you can add respective methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:IS_FIRST_LOGIN])
{
    showYourPage();
}
#########In your Page#######
-(void) acceptButtonClicked
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:IS_FIRST_LOGIN];
}
```

Comment: i used this logic inside the viewDidLoad but its not working showing Warning: Attempt to present <xmlexpViewController2: 0x8082660> on <xmlexpViewController: 0x807ffa0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
self.userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *str = [self.userDefaults valueForKey:@"SecondLaunch"];
NSLog(@"the string value is : %@",str);

if ([str isEqualToString:@"Second"]) {
    NSLog(@"It's Second Launch");
} else {
    NSLog(@"It's First Launch");
    [self.userDefaults setObject:@"Second" forKey:@"SecondLaunch"];
    [self.userDefaults synchronize];        
}
```