# NSUserDefaults not being saved in iOS Simulator?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios-simulator, nsuserdefaults

My `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` are not being saved. Everytime I close the app and start it again, it reverts back. I don't have my iOS device handy so I am not sure if this will happen on device, but none of the other apps are doing this in simulator which leads me to believe there's something wrong with my code. I don't know what part of code I should include here, it's just simple add/modify keys in `NSUserDefaults` and as I said it runs fine during the app, but not after i restart it...

I know I can call `synchronize` but Apple advices against it and says I should only call it if it's a must... so.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: why don't you try and call synchronize just to see if it works? you can also check its return value for errors...

Comment: Hi,
I just did that at applicationwillterminate method, but doesn't work.. :(

Comment: Try to do it in `applicationDidEnterBackground:`, as I suggest in my answer below. See this for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139588/applicationwillterminate-in-ios-4-0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your process is possibly terminated improperly so that `NSUserDefaults` do not have a chance to be stored. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418894/nsuserdefaults-not-saving-properly) and mostly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622754/nsuserdefault-not-able-to-save-values/2622940#2622940).

The suggestion in the second post I link to is to call `synchronize` in `applicationDidEnterBackground:`

Keep also in mind that terminating your app by stopping it in Xcode most often does not save user defaults.

Comment: Sergio is right.  If you want your values to be saved in the simulator when you quit out, you **have** to call `synchronize`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you restarting from Xcode / debugger? Try sending the app to background with the Home button first. I think the framework synchronizes automatically then.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your reply, I send it to background and then double clicked the home button and closed the app. Then, when I start it from simulator again, it crashed. But in XCode if I build -> run, it doesn't crash, but my nsuserdefaults aren't saved...hmm

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand about the way, you are accessing the `NSUserDefault`, The static function you used `sharedDefaults` with `NSUserDefault` does'nt exist in Apple Documentation

Use As below to access `NSUserDefault`

```
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

For more read the blog post for using of `NSUserDefault`.

[iPhone Programming Tutorial – Saving/Retrieving Data Using NSUserDefaults](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/)

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant. Fixed my question.

Comment: @user635064  : Check the blog tutorial link for NSUserDefault.

Comment: I know how to use NSUserDefaults.. it was a mistake, I wasn't copy pasting my code I thought it was sharedDefaults...thanks for your help.