# NSUserDefaults, saving data issue

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults

So I have an app that lets you put in a title and an author on the front page, then you hit enter and it will go into the actual features of the app.  I want to save the data with NSUserDefaults, so that when they click the enter button, it saves it ****AND*** goes into the next view.  I have it setup with the storybord already to go into the next view, but when I use this code:

```
-(IBAction)enter:(id)sender {  
  titleString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[title text]];
  [title setText:titleString];

  NSUserDefaults *titleDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [titleDefault setObject:titleString forKey:@"stringkey"];
  authorString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[author text]];
  [title setText:authorString];

  NSUserDefaults *authorDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [authorDefault setObject:authorString forKey:@"stringkey2"];
}
```

It will always crash when you hit the button.  I have all the NSStrings defined and such, so I don't see what the problem is.  I also have it loading with:

```
title.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"stringkey"];
author.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"stringkey2"];
```

Under the viewdidload, so can I have some help as to why this wouldn't work?

Comment: give us the exception log please

Comment: So you are initializing your strings with the format of the `text` and then setting the `text` to the strings you just initialized?  Why?

Answer (score 1):

Just to *optimize* your `-enter:`method:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:title.text forKey:@"stringkey"];
[defaults setObject:author.text forKey:@"stringkey2"];
[defaults synchronize]; // this will store them instantly!
```

For the crash: can you please provide us with the exact crash log? Maybe your Button is linked to an unknown selector...

Comment: Okay, now it doesn't crash, but it just won't load them once you open them again.

Answer (score 0):

First, there are a few questions about this: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418894/nsuserdefaults-not-saving-properly?rq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622754/why-is-nsuserdefaults-not-saving-my-values/2622940#2622940).  Try searching around first, and at least let people know why the duplicate questions you found didn't work for you.

Secondly, I think you might benefit from adding a `synchronize`.  Use this:

```
titleString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[title text]];
[title setText:titleString];

 NSUserDefaults *titleDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[titleDefault setObject:titleString forKey:@"stringkey"];

[titleDefault synchronize];

authorString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[author text]];
[author setText:authorString];

NSUserDefaults *authorDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[authorDefault setObject:authorString forKey:@"stringkey2"];

[authorDefault synchronize];
```

I also changed the `[title setText:authorString];` line to `[author setText:authorString];`.  I do, however, think it is a bit redundant the way you are allocating the `NSString`s to the value of the text fields and then setting the text back to the value of the string you created.  I don't get the need.  Anyway, hope this helps.